# Heroku not showing CSS updates in javascript app

Tags: javascript, css, git, heroku, deploying

My heroku app is not displaying recent CSS updates. I did get add, commit, and push to github, then I did git push heroku master.

I have looked at other posts related to this topic with no success. Most reference rails which I am not using. These suggestions are irrelevant to me - they are unknown commands in bash and again, I am not using ruby/rails
rake assets:precompile (doesn't work)
bundle exec rake assets:precompile (doesn't work)

I did heroku restart in case that would help somehow, don't even know what it does but gave it a shot.

Git status says branch is up-to-date with master.

Here is my app link - it will be obvious where updates are not showing...
https://glacial-cove-60103.herokuapp.com/#

My github repository:
https://github.com/carlynsullivan/Manatees-Gone-Wild

Comment: I think there is problem with script moving down in index.html

Comment: please give the answer to your question below so that anyone having the same issue can consult your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular case turned out to be a matter of clearing the cache. Sometimes an old version of a page can be stored and displayed even upon refreshing, and clearing the cache gets rid of this issue.

[I used this link to clear my cache.](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic)

You can also just press <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>delete</kbd> on a mac.